# How to mount cifs with kerberos for a generic user?

Tags: mount, cifs, aws, kerberos, workspaces

I am able to mount a corporate shared directory on my AWS Workspace manually but I need to do this for all users.

```bsh
$ sudo ksu
[sudo] password for <Domain>\<User.Name>: 
Leaving uid as root (0)
$ mount -t cifs //<Domain>/<Path> /home/*/<Mount\ Point\ Name> -o multiuser,sec=krb5
$ exit
```

I need this to work for all users which means I need a general solution.

Amazon Workspaces create one virtual machine per user.   I need to create an image of my OS to share with other users.  So even if I were in some way to create a fstab entry with my credentials, those credentials wouldn't be valid for any other user's Workspace.

I may have the wrong end of the stick, this may not be achievable.

I imagine something like the above, **might** work by creating a script that runs at user log-on, as the user which uses ksu to create the context and then mounts a directory in the user's home directory.  Therefore the user's credentials wouldn't be available at run time as they'd be just logging in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to set out the store, so as to speak.  The goal, mount a network share when the user logs into to the Workspace.  The constraints: must use kerberos, don't know who the user is ahead of time, can't use any stored credentials.

The above is as far as I can see a blind alley.

So the solution that I'm using:  pam_mount

Edit two files:

1. /etc/pam.d/system-auth
2. /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml

Editing the first file may be optional depending upon your distribution, add two lines:

```
auth        optional      pam_mount.so
session     optional      pam_mount.so
```

Try to follow the convention of your system-auth and add these lines to the appropriate sections.

Add the following to the second file:

```
<!-- Using CIFS -->
  <volume
      fstype="cifs"
      path="//server_name/share_name"
      mountpoint="~/mnt/share_name"
      uid="10000-19999"
      options="sec=krb5i,vers=3.0,cruid=%(USERUID)"
  />
```

Update this part to reflect your needs.

For further information please review the source pages for the above:

[TechRepublic - Using pam_mount to automount filesystems at login](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/using-pam-mount-to-automount-filesystems-at-login/)

[Arch Wiki - pam_mount](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pam_mount)